# How to change witch side of the cube will be rendered?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, rendering

As you can see in the image below, the rendered faces of the cube are the inner ones, but that is not what I wanted. How can I render the outer faces of the cube with this shader that I've created? Thank you!

[image: The cube with inner faces being shown, I want to render the outer faces]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post your shader code.

Comment: I just realized that I can't send you code because I'm using Shader Graph. I'll post the image of the graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to solve the problem editing two things in Shader Graph's Master Node

1. Marked the "Two Sided" option
2. Select "Multiply" for Blend option

This solved my problem pretty well (Images Below). I hope this helps anyone in the future. Anyway, thank you for the help!

[image: Solving problem changing PBR Master Node]

[image: Image of the new cube!]

Answer (score 1):

In your shader add or change your **[Backface culling](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html)** mode to this key:

```
Cull Back
```

Comment: How do I do that on Shader Graph?